# Node.js could resolve the dependencies only when being executed by "docker-compose.yaml"

Tags: node.js, docker

The distributive (the source code is not included) of my project is:

[image]

If to run `npm install --no-package-lock` and then start the application by

```bash
node FrontServerEntryPoint.js --environment production
```

everything will works file.

Next, if to run the `Dockerfile` with content

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/example.com

COPY . /var/www/example.com

RUN npm install --no-package-lock

CMD [ "node", "FrontServerEntryPoint.js", "--environment", "production" ]
```

everything will work fine too.

But if to execute the below `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  node_js:

    container_name: FrontServer
    build: .
    ports: [ "3000:3000" ]
    # TODO depends_on: [ "Database ]

    volumes:

      - .:/var/www/example.jp

  database:

    container_name: Database

    image: postgres
    ports: [ "5432:5432" ]

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}

    volumes:
      - Database:/data/example.jp

volumes:
  Database: {}
```

it will be the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions-nodejs'
Require stack:
- /var/www/example.jp/FrontServerEntryPoint.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    // ...
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/var/www/example.com/FrontServerEntryPoint.js' ]
```

As it is already clear from the previous experiments, '@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions-nodejs' should be installed. But if you want the listing of the `package.json` for the confirmation, I'll post it:

```
{
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "9.0.11",
    "@nestjs/core": "9.0.11",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "9.0.11",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "9.0.1",
    "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions": "1.6.0-alpha.4",
    "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions-nodejs": "1.6.0-alpha.3",
    "express-handlebars": "6.0.6",
    "hbs": "4.2.0",
    "pg": "8.8.0",
    "typeorm": "0.3.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does deleting the `volumes:` block for the `node_js` container help?  If the container path matches the image's `WORKDIR` then it hides absolutely everything that the `Dockerfile` does, at which point you're not really usefully using Docker's immutable image system at all.

Comment: (You probably don't want to use the `npm install --no-package-lock` option, the lock file is useful in making sure indirect dependencies don't get upgraded unexpectedly.  You don't need to specify `container_name:` in the Compose file.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for the comments. "Does deleting the `volumes: block` for the `node_js` container help?" - Yes! But is it fine? (In my case, unlike the `database` service, there is no the valuable data in `node_js`)

Comment: @DavidMaze "You probably don't want to use the npm install --no-package-lock option" - I am not planning to install the new dependencies inside the same image extended from "node:16-alpine". The package.json listed above is for deployment only; the source code is using the other package.json.

Comment: @DavidMaze "You don't need to specify container_name: in the Compose file." - why? Without it the automatic name will be assigned, but the manually assigned one is more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `volumes:` block in your Compose file is hiding everything that's done in the Dockerfile, including the `npm install` step.  It's unnecessary and you can delete it.

This will resolve the import issue you're seeing, because the `node_modules` directory on your host is different from the directory in your image.  The Node interpreters and underlying operating systems may be different too, and you want to use the version in the image and not the version from the host.